# Rails validation on fields not tied to any model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with the following form:

```
<%= form_tag(:action => 'index') do %>
  From: <%= text_field_tag(:from, params[:from]) %><br />
  To: <%= text_field_tag(:to, params[:to]) %><br />
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Which displays a listing based on the date range provided by the :from and :to params.

How do I do presence and compare validations on the two text boxes which are not tied to any model or table?

Thanks!
Corix

Answer (score 1):

You can use a model that's not persisted to the database.

```
class DateRange
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :from, :to
  validates_presence_of :from, :to

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
date_range = DateRange.new(:from => params[:from], :to => params[:to])
if date_range.valid?
  #do stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chris. However, It didn't work for me. Do I need to change the form code as well?